# continuation of program when user inputs yes

Tags: java, while-loop, repeat

Ok so my program works fine but at the end it asks if the user would like to input another set of integers and if they type *"yes"* the process starts over. My program is starting over, but it keeps all the same user inputs so it just keeps repeating the same output from their original input.

Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PositiveNegative {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Input a list of integers (end with 0): ");
        int nums = input.nextInt();

        String answer;
        int pos = 0;
        int neg = 0;
        int total = 0;
        int count = 0;
        double avg = 0;

        do {
            while (nums != 0) {
                if (nums >= 1) {
                    pos++;
                } else {
                   neg++;
                }
                total = total + nums;
                count++;

                avg = total * 1.0 / count;

                System.out.print("Input a list of integers (End with 0): ");
                nums = input.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.print("# of positives are: " + pos + "\n" + "# of negatives are : " + neg + "\n" + "The total: " + total + "\n" + "The average: " + avg);
            System.out.print("\nWould you like to continue with new inputs? ");
            answer = input.next();
        } while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));
    }  
}
```

My current output looks like this:

> Input a list of integers (end with 0): 1
>
> Input a list of integers (End with 0): 2
>
> Input a list of integers (End with 0): -1
>
> Input a list of integers (End with 0): 3
>
> Input a list of integers (End with 0): 0
>
> number of positives are: 3
>
> number of negatives are : 1
>
> The total: 5
>
> The average: 1.25
>
> Would you like to continue with new inputs? yes
>
> number of positives are: 3
>
> number of negatives are : 1
>
> The total: 5
>
> The average: 1.25
>
> Would you like to continue with new inputs?

Its supposed to look like this:

> number of positive inputs:   3
>
> number of negative inputs:   1
>
> The total:              5.0
>
> The average:            1.25
>
> Would you like to continue with new inputs? yes
>
> Input a list of integers (end with 0): 0
>
> No numbers were entered except 0
>
> Would you like to continue with new inputs? no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PositiveNegative {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String answer;
        do {
            System.out.print("Input a list of integers (end with 0): ");
            int nums = input.nextInt();

            int pos = 0;
            int neg = 0;
            int total = 0;
            int count = 0;
            double avg = 0;

            while (nums != 0) {
                if (nums >= 1) {
                    pos++;
                } else {
                   neg++;
                }
                total = total + nums;
                count++;

                avg = total * 1.0 / count;

                System.out.print("Input a list of integers (End with 0): ");
                nums = input.nextInt();
            }

            if(count == 0) {
                System.out.print("No numbers were entered except 0");
            } else {
                System.out.print("# of positives are: " + pos + "\n" + "# of negatives are : " + neg + "\n" + "The total: " + total + "\n" + "The average: " + avg);
            }
            System.out.print("\nWould you like to continue with new inputs? ");
            answer = input.next();
        } while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of your variables should go inside the `do ... while` block, so that they can be initialized if the user wants to continue.

Replace

```
 int pos = 0;
 int neg = 0;
 int total = 0;
 int count = 0;
 double avg = 0;

 do{
     //...
```

with

```
do {
    int pos = 0;
    int neg = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int count = 0;
    double avg = 0;
    //...
```

Comment: with that it immediately gives all 0 outputs after the user inputs their values the first time.

Comment: You need to change the inner loop to a do ... while too then